cloudflare worker to router subpath to multiple subdomains
I use cloudflare pages to deploy static website and assign subdomains for each one under same root domain.
when user access subpath like the following:
rootdomain.com/generator/subdomaina 
rootdomain.com/generator/subdomainb 
rootdomain.com/generator/subdomainc 

what user actually see contents from and url continue the same
subdomaina.rootdomain.com 
subdomainb.rootdomain.com 
subdomainc.rootdomain.com 

subdomains can be accessed successfully
I try to use cloudflare worker to achieve this,but it always give me 404
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const url = new URL(request.url)

  // Check if the host is rootdomain.com or www.rootdomain.com
  if (url.hostname !== 'rootdomain.com') {
    // Pass the request to the original destination
    return fetch(request)
  }

  // Handle generator paths
  if (url.pathname.startsWith('/generator/')) {


    const pathParts = url.pathname.split('/generator/');
    if (pathParts.length < 2) {
      return new Response('Not Found', { status: 404 });
    }

    const subdomain = pathParts[1].trim();
    const validSubdomains = ['fontgenerator', 'incorrectquotesgenerator', 'randompokemongenerator'];
    console.log(`Extracted subdomain: ${subdomain}`);

    if (!validSubdomains.includes(subdomain)) {
      return new Response('Not Found', { status: 404 });
    }

    const targetHost = `${subdomain}.rootdomain.com`;
    const targetUrl = `https://${targetHost}`;
    console.log(`Target URL: ${targetUrl}`);

    const modifiedRequest = new Request(targetUrl, {
      method: request.method,
      headers: request.headers,
      redirect: 'follow'
    });
    console.log(`Original request method: ${request.method}`);

    return fetch(modifiedRequest);
  }

  // Handle image paths
  if (url.pathname.startsWith('/image/')) {
    const pathParts = url.pathname.split('/image/');
    if (pathParts.length < 2) {
      return new Response('Not Found', { status: 404 });
    }

    const action = pathParts[1].trim(); // Get the action part (e.g., removebg)
    const validActions = ['removebg']; // List your valid actions
    console.log(`Extracted action: ${action}`);

    if (!validActions.includes(action)) {
      return new Response('Not Found', { status: 404 });
    }

    const targetHost = `${action}.rootdomain.com`;
    const targetUrl = `https://${targetHost}`;
    console.log(`Target URL: ${targetUrl}`);

    const modifiedRequest = new Request(targetUrl, {
      method: request.method,
      headers: request.headers,
      redirect: 'follow'
    });

    return fetch(modifiedRequest);
  }

  // Handle markdown paths
  if (url.pathname.startsWith('/markdown/')) {
    const pathParts = url.pathname.split('/markdown/');
    if (pathParts.length < 2) {
      return new Response('Not Found', { status: 404 });
    }

    const action = pathParts[1].trim(); // Get the action part for markdown
    const validMarkdownActions = ['markdowntopdf', 'preview']; // List your valid markdown actions
    console.log(`Extracted markdown action: ${action}`);

    if (!validMarkdownActions.includes(action)) {
      return new Response('Not Found', { status: 404 });
    }

    const targetHost = `${action}.rootdomain.com`;
    const targetUrl = `https://${targetHost}`;
    console.log(`Target URL: ${targetUrl}`);

    const modifiedRequest = new Request(targetUrl, {
      method: request.method,
      headers: request.headers,
      redirect: 'follow'
    });

    return fetch(modifiedRequest);
  }

  // For all other paths, ignore and return a default response
  return new Response('Path not supported', { status: 200 });
}


